# Split a timestamp column into separate columns

Tags: r

I want to split a 'timestamp' column in my dataset into two separate one, the dataset is very lengthy

[image]

I expect two different columns, one for date '2014-09-22'and other for time '07:47:00'

Comment: Since R does not have a time object only a date and datetime object, thus I would not recommend splitting the column in two.  Of course this all depends on what additional analysis you intend.

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e! I want to sort the data by individual year but I have problem in sorting it successfully. If i use the data I have and sort, either the variables or the rows are missing in the resulting dataset

Comment: R doesn't, but lubridate, I believe, does.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `python` if you want a solution in the `R` language?

Comment: what's the class of your timestamp? Are these just strings, or is it something like POSIXct/lt?

Comment: @chandanKB, "I want to sort the data by individual year but I have problem in sorting it successfully." This is a better question than one posted.  Provide some sample data and the code you tried, you will have better success.  See this for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon if you there is a solution for this in python that is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strsplit function and split on a space. That's implying your data has no spaces after which it doesn't seem so.

```
df$nwcolumn <- strsplit(df$timestamp, " ")
```

Comment: Can you call str(df) on your df? or say what class is the timestamp?

Comment: `strsplit` will split one element (string) at a time, but here `strsplit(df$timestamp, " ")` we expect `strsplit` process whole column, which is not the `strsplit` was designed to do. The only way to use this code is to pass it into a loop and process one element (string) at a time

Comment: @Xderic the class of timestamp is a factor

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c("2014-09-32 07:47:00", "2016-09-13 14:32:00", "2017-09-18 12:42:00"))
df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"), sep = " ")
```

Output is:

```
A           B
<chr>       <chr>
2014-09-32  07:47:00        
2016-09-13  14:32:00        
2017-09-18  12:42:00
```